# How to mock REST service response in actual code flow for lower environments

Tags: spring, rest

I have a service which calls the REST Api and that REST API call is chargeable, so i want when we deploy the code in Dev & QA environment, mock response should be returned while actual functionality testing. 
How can i achieve that ?

```
Mock Rest API response in actual code flow
```

Comment: Search around `mockRestTempate = new RestTemplate();
  mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(mockRestTempate).build();

  synchroService.setRestTemplate(mockRestTempate);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint for your api shouldn't be hard-coded in the code, instead you can set the endpoint in a properties file.

ie. In a file like `.../myapp/src/resources/application.properties`

```
some.service.api.endpoint=someservice.com/api
```

Then in your code you can use Spring's `@Value` annotation to get the value.

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceApi {

    @Value("some.service.api.endpoint")
    private String endpoint;

    // ...
```

While in development, the property can point to some mock endpoint that you've set up yourself, or if the api supports it, a sandbox endpoint for the api.